# Do e-ink devices suffer from burn-in?

Tags: e-ink

Back in the bad old days of CRT computer monitors, computer users were confronted with the problem of [burn-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_burn-in), in which a monitor that displayed the same image for too long would eventually have the image "burnt-in" - that is, the image would persist on the screen even after the display was changed to something else.

**Do any e-ink displays suffer from a similar issue?**

Answer (score 6):

No they don't. Otherwise Kindle screen pictures/ and similar picture on other e-ink devices would have been discouraged and the screen would had been blank on shutdown.

Answer (score 5):

I have found some of my Kindles have ghosting on the screens. I've bought at least 30 e-ink kindles, many previously owned by other owners. The ghosting tends to vanish as I use the devices, so it may be related to other causes e.g. where the device doesn't refresh every pixel.

See http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/common-problems-and-solutions-for-your-kindle-pape.html and the tip on using Alt+G on Kindle DX and Kindle Keyboard devices e.g. http://thehowto.wikidot.com/kindle-dx